# Complexity order f(x) = x vs g(x) = log (x)^(log (x))

Tags: math, time-complexity, computer-science

What is Big-O complexity order for: f(x) = x  vs  g(x) =  log (x)^(log (x)) ?

Comment: wolfram alpha is pretty useful for questions like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28x%29%5Elog%28x%29&lk=4

Comment: I tried that, but what plot should I compare ? How to vary 'c' constant and finalize the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to understand this with example. Consider log represents 2 based logarithm. We can ignore constant as we want behavior at asymptote. Running time `f(x)` vs `g(x)` as x follows:

```
x=2^1: f(x) = 2^1 = 2    ; g(x) = log(2^1)^log(2^1) = 1^1 = 1     ;f(x) > g(x)
x=2^2: f(x) = 2^2 = 4    ; g(x) = log(2^2)^log(2^2) = 2^2 = 4     ;f(x) = g(x)
x=2^3: f(x) = 2^3 = 8    ; g(x) = log(2^3)^log(2^3) = 3^3 = 27    ;f(x) < g(x)
x=2^4: f(x) = 2^4 = 16   ; g(x) = log(2^4)^log(2^4) = 4^4 = 256   ;f(x) < g(x)
...
x=2^100: f(x) = 2^100    ; g(x) = log(2^100)^log(2^100) = 100^100 ;f(x) << g(x)
```

So as x approaches infinity running time of `f(x)` is way less than `g(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `x > 0` because `g(x)` is only well defined for those `x`. This means we are allowed to make the substitution `x = e^t`, which gives us

```
 f(x) = e^t
 g(x) = t^t
```

and it becomes immediately clear that `g(x) > f(x)` for all `t > e`, that is, for all `x > e^e`. In particular, this means that `f(x) = O(g(x))`, and in fact it would be easy to prove that `f(x) = o(g(x))`.